# Database SQL Problem

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This command is working on some SQL Server databases, but not on others.

```
select Cast(Cast(DateDiff(mm,'20110608','20110708') as decimal(5,2))/12 as decimal(5,2))
```

It either returns this error

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

or works and returns:

```
 0.08
```

Is there any settings I should change on the database?

Comment: Why would you cast it twice? Do the math and then cast the result.  And why would you need decimals anyway if your measurements are whole days?

Comment: What do you want to do? Are you trying to get the duration in years?

Comment: @mikeY, you need decimals to avoid integer math in the division.

Comment: @HLGEM - True, but see my answer. If you use `12.0` instead of `12` for the divisor, SQL Server will do decimal rather than integer division.

Comment: And you don't need to cast both top and bottom, only 1 part needs to be decimal to get decimal math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it by setting:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Different instances running the same version or different versions of SQL Server? The only thing that stands out is your date format (e.g. '20110608'). Possibly not supported in all SQL Server versions?

Anyway, try this instead and see if you get the overflow error:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(Decimal(5, 2), DATEDIFF(MM, '20110608', '20110708') / 12.0);
```